# Set Python environment used at startup/command prompt

Tags: bash, python, gnome-terminal, startup, environment-variables

I noticed that on startup and from the command prompt (ALT + F2) Ubuntu uses a different Python environment (namely 2.7.17) than what it uses from terminal (currently 3.7.7)

(I checked the command prompt with `gnome-terminal -- bash -c  "python -V ; read"`)

Currently, this prevents me to use nvim with a plugin if I open it at startup.

How could I make Ubuntu use Python 3 (and perhaps with a specific environment) also in theses cases?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? (AFACT no supported version uses 3.7.7.)

Comment: Currently 18.04 (but thinking about upgrading to 20.04). I am not strict about the specific version, but wondering how I could change the one used at startup/command prompt as I would prefer them to be consistent with the one in the terminal.

Comment: On my 18.04 (in a VM) `python`, which typically means python2, does not exist by default. `python3 -V` gives "Python 3.6.9". The standard way to use python3 is to call `python3`.